# Does Xcode 4.2 beta also come with iOS SDK 4?

Tags: xcode, ios, ios4, xcode4, ios5

If I install Xcode 4.2 and iOS SDK 5 beta (Snow Leopard), will I still be able to build and run for iOS SDK 4?

Comment: We cannot talk about Xcode 4.2 here, go to the devforums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say yes. When you download iOS SDK 4 you can still build for iOS SDK 3. So I don't see why it would be different this time.

Comment: so if using xcode 4.2 and build the app using sdk 4, will it be ok for submission in the app store?